# jQuery/CSS hovering globally rather than per element

Tags: jquery, css, image, hover

I'm using this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('.trow1 img, .description').hover(function(){     
         $('.description p').removeClass('description_content'); 
    },     
    function(){    
        $('.description p').addClass('description_content');      
    });
});
```

to create a small hover over top of a banner listing with a few text links.

Basically the jQuery removes the class `description_content` which is doing `display:none;`

The problem is that when I hover over one image, the hover for every image comes up at once I want it to just hover one at a time.

http://jsfiddle.net/omouqh37/2/

Comment: I can't find the images with hover effects. Are they hidden behind a login?

Comment: Woops. i didn't link right to it. it's the toplist page.. i changed it in the jsfiddle

Comment: show the html your script refers to in the question. We shouldn't have to try to find the code within an iframe in a demo. Questions should be self contained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$('.description p').removeClass('description_content');
```

To

```
$(this).parent().find('.description p').removeClass('description_content');
```

Here this should be enough:

http://jsfiddle.net/tLp5409f/

Read these:

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

http://api.jquery.com/find/

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Important concept from class-selector link - Description: Selects ***all*** elements with the given class.

One more thing to consider: you don't require javascript for this, look into pseudo elements and using ::before and ::after, but be aware that this may have less support that jquery, so it may not be the better option depending on how cross-platform you need this to be

Comment: Try making a more isolated case in your fiddle, I can't see anything happening at all when I hover over the image

Comment: It doesn't work if you run the jquery on the jsfiddle, you have to open it in a new tab, run the jquery and then hover the image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joe Sager

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('.trow1 img, .description').hover(function(){     
         $(this).parent().find('.description p').removeClass('description_content'); 
    },     
    function(){    
$(this).parent().find('.description p').addClass('description_content');  

    });
});
```

Comment: Is this answer different from Joe's? You should probably delete this and select his answer (green checkmark).